# AngularJS Directives check for flag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would have a question to angularJS directives. 
I have the following directive- Code:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <div class="badge pull-right" tooltip="Role" tooltip-append-to-body="true" editable-text="vm.mytext">{{vm.mytext}}</div>
...
```

and in this code there is

> editable-text="vm.mytext"

but I use the directive a lot of times an I don't need to edit the

> ... div class="badge pull-right" tooltip="Role" ...

every time. I use the directive like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <as-directive-name item="item"></as-directive-name>
</div>
```

My question now would be if it is possible to user the directive like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <as-directive-name item="item" roleEditable="false"></as-directive-name>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility to assign a flag roleEditable and to check this flag in the directive-html similarly to this:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
        <div class="badge pull-right" tooltip="Role" tooltip-append-to-body="true" if(roleEditable == true) {editable-text="vm.mytext"}>{{vm.mytext}}</div>
```

Thanks a lot for help!
All the best!

**[EDIT]**
Here is the code of the directive:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myproject.institution')
    .directive('asInstitutionPanel', asInstitutionPanel);

function asInstitutionPanel() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            asInstitutionUserConnection: '='  
        },
        controller: InstitutionPanelController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/... .directive.html'
    };

    return directive;
}

InstitutionPanelController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function InstitutionPanelController($scope) {
    $scope.vm = this; // assumes controllerAs: vm
    var vm = this;
    vm.institutionUserConnection = this.asInstitutionUserConnection;
}
})();
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know if is this what you are looking for, but, if you wrap your in a fileset tag, and use ng-disabled, you can use a parameter in the directive to enable or disable the whole div. Regards!!

Comment: please post the JS code for the directive so I can use that to give you an answer.

Comment: Hi, I have posted the javascript code above. It would be great if someone could help me - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this you are looking for?

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <directive flag="true"></directive>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.directive('directive', directive)

directive.$inject = [];

function directive() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                flag: '='
            },
            template: '<fieldset ng-disabled="flag"><input type="text"></fieldset>',

            controllerAs: 'moduloCtrl',
            link:function(scope){
                console.log(scope);
            }
        };
    }
```

If you change flag you can enable and disable the input inside.

Here is the codepen http://codepen.io/arielcessario/pen/RPdNvL?editors=101

I hope this helps.

Regards!!

**[EDIT]**

If you want to remove the attribute, you can add something like this to your directive:

```
link:function(scope, element, attributes)
{element[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].removeAttribute('editable-text') ;
}
```

If you change your structure and you want to know how many childNodes to append and which index you'd use (I don't really know if is the best way, but it works for me), you can do something like this and look in the list of childNodes:

console.log(element);

You should be able to see the whole directive structure and all of the attributes, also if you need for some reason, you can change the value of a node using:

element[0].childNodes[n]...childNodes[n].attributes['node-name'].nodeValue = value;

Regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer - it goes into the right direction. Currently I don't know how I disable a "html attribute" like " <div ... **editable-text="..."** ...>" in my div container - is this also possible. And the second one is that I use "**templateUrl**" instead of "template". It would be great if there would be also any solution for this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi! Glad to hear is going in the right direction! For the second part, you can just paste the code in your directive.html, and use templateUrl instead (tried locally and works fine). For the first part, I don't quite understand what you mean by disable an "html attibute". Can you clarify this for me? Regards!

Comment: Here is the div element in my directive.html: <div class="badge pull-right" tooltip="Role" tooltip-append-to-body="true" if(roleEditable == true) {editable-text="vm.mytext"}>{{vm.mytext}}</div>, at the first usage I need **editable-text="vm.mytext"** and at the second usage I don't need **editable-text="vm.mytext"**. Is there a possibility fo switching on and off this attribute?

Comment: There's one more question, you want to turn it off according the amount of times your directives have been created?

Comment: No, I will decide if I use the directive whether I will switch on or switch off editable ot text. Thanks!